# Task.WaitAll and AggregateException handling

Tags: c#, httpclient, aggregateexception

I've got a little program that needs to update a lot of row statuses with async batched api calls.

I've got an HttpClient instance created with all the constants of the api call set, and then I launch the calls asynchronously in batches of 100.  Then I do a Task.WaitAll() for the whole set.

I put a catch(AggregateException) block around Task.WaitAll() to log if there were any errors, then I try to process the ones that succeeded.

I've started getting errors lately (usually timeouts/cancels), but the thing that has me scratching my head is that the bottom "process the successes" loop is throwing *another* AggregateException.

The Task.WaitAll() throws one with, say, 2 or 3 timeouts out of 100 requests.  Then the bottom loop that's supposed to process the successes throws another one with a *single* InnerException.

My guess is that either

1. When there's an AggregateException on Task.WaitAll(), it might not be actually waiting for all 100 to be complete or
2. The second loop touching apiResult.Exception != null (or the 2nd if with apiResult.Exception == null && apiResult.Result != null) is causing another AggregateException to be thrown with the single task being examined.

Is looking at asiResult.Exception the wrong way to see if a task errored out?

Thanks

```
    private static async Task<Tuple<ApiStatus, long>> LaunchApiRequest(string id)
    {
        var result = ApiStatus.Unknown;
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        // This approach throws exception for any non-200 response, which is expensive.  Unlike WebRequest, the exception doesn't give you a respose object.  
        // This api returns json describing the error so we need to make the call and the deserialization separate steps to the errors in line with the code.
        // var json = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<JsonElement>("?newsID=" + id); 
        var req1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "?ID=" + id);
        var resp = await _httpClient.SendAsync(req1);
        sw.Stop();
        var reqTime = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            result = ApiStatus.NotFound;
        else if (!resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result = ApiStatus.Error;
        else
        {
            var json = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JsonElement>(await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());    // System.Text.Json
            // look at json response here
        }

        return new Tuple<ApiStatus, long>(result, reqTime);
    }

...

    try
    {
         // loop construct to get more batches
...
                    int asyncExceptions = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        Task.WaitAll(batchRequests);
                    }
                    catch(AggregateException e)
                    {
                        asyncExceptions = e.InnerExceptions.Count;
                        var firstE = e.InnerExceptions[0];
                        _logger.Error($"{asyncExceptions.ToString()} api requests out of {batchRequests.Length.ToString()} threw exceptions.  Sample exception: {firstE.Message}\nStackTrace: {firstE.StackTrace}");
                    }

                    if (asyncExceptions == batchRequests.Length)
                    {   // All requests in this batch errored out; api must be down
                        throw new Exception("All api requests in batch returned errors.  Must be a problem with the api.");
                    }

                    long apiBatchTimeTotal = 0, apiBatchTimeMin = long.MaxValue, apiBatchTimeMax = long.MinValue;
                    int countErrs = 0, count404s = 0;
                    r = 0;
                    int lastGoodRequest = 0;
                    foreach (var apiResult in batchRequests)
                    {
                        if (apiResult.Exception != null || apiResult.Result == null || apiResult.Result.Item1 ==  ApiStatus.Error) countErrs++;
                        else if (apiResult.Result.Item1 == ApiStatus.NotFound) count404s++;

                        if (countErrs == 0 && count404s == 0) lastGoodRequest = r;  // if we haven't hit any 404s or errors this batch, move the stake in the sand up to here.

                        if (apiResult.Exception == null && apiResult.Result != null)
                        {
                            var callTime = apiResult.Result.Item2;
                            if (callTime < apiBatchTimeMin) apiBatchTimeMin = callTime;
                            if (callTime > apiBatchTimeMax) apiBatchTimeMax = callTime;
                            apiBatchTimeTotal += callTime;
                        }
                        r++;
                    }
...
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            var firstE = e.InnerExceptions[0];
            _logger.Fatal($"{e.InnerExceptions.Count.ToString()} api requests threw exceptions.  Sample exception: {firstE.Message}\nStackTrace: {firstE.StackTrace}");
            SendEMailMessage(EmailRecipients, "Batch Api Status Failure!", $"Sample Error: {firstE.Message}\nStackTrace: {firstE.StackTrace}", "High");
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Task.WaitAll` and not `await Task.WhenAll`? And why not just use `var result = await apiResult;` in the loop, in order to get exceptions to unwrap properly? Also `reql` and `resp` need `using` to dispose them.